# Convert times in whole column into float import from csv using panda

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

In my csv file I have time column with three data column. I need to convert time into float using panda. But it gives me an error ,invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'g'
Can you please suggest me to solve this error?
My code is,

```js
def time_to_float(t):
    """ convert "hh:mm:ss" to float (0, 1) only of the correct format """
    if t == '-':
        return None
    a = [int(i) for i in t.split(":")]
    if len(a) == 3:
        return round((a[0] + a[1] / 60 + a[2] / 3600) / 24, 5)
    else:
        return t


def pick_column(data_, n, start=1):
    """ pick all the n'th column data starting from "start" """
    return [time_to_float(data_[i][n]) for i in range(start, len(data_))]

data = pd.read_csv('data4.csv')
data = [i for i in data]


Time = pick_column(data, 0)
g = pick_column(data, 1)
p = pick_column(data, 2)
c = pick_column(data, 3)
y = pick_column(data, 4)



print(Time)
print(g)
print(p)
print(c)
print(y)
```

my data set is

```js
Time    g  p   c  y
0:06:15 141 NaN NaN 141
0:08:00 NaN 10 NaN 117
0:09:00 NaN 15 NaN 103
0:09:25 95 NaN NaN 95
0:09:30 NaN NaN 50 93
```

Comment: Since, I don't have your csv, can you run a few print statements in the function for a[0], a[1], a[2], _data[I][n], and len(_data)? I am kind of curious to check what the output will be.

Comment: While I gave print statement to these functions and it is showing errors , they are not defined in my code. I am going to design a neural network to predict values with time and this is gives me an error time can't convert into float. Thtat's why I tried to convert time into float. Can you give me any suggestions to solve this error? @Matthew

Comment: are you trying to convert per day basis ? 0:1:0 = +0+60seconds +0 = 60 seconds, something like this ?

Comment: yes I'm trying to do that one. @user3280146

Comment: @awa please check answer,  that should solve your problem. And that answer follows 24hrs timeformat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this

this is your sample Time

```
print(df['Time'])
1:06:15
```

To convert this into seconds per day basis you can do like this

```
df['TimeFloat'] = (pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Time']).astype(np.int64)/10**9)%86400
```

Taking modulus of 86400 is used because in one day there are 86400 seconds
You can modify the modulus value according to your conversions (seconds, minute, milliseconds)
Also if you need conversion in `int`, you can simply use `//` instead of `/`

Final df would be this

```
   Time  TimeFloat
1:06:15     3975.0
```

Comment: Thank you its solved my problem. @user3280146 . But I'm facing with another problem. Actually I want to predict the values with time using neural network. Then after floating how I can add this results into my train & test   with other data?

Comment: thats an another question.So you have to ask again.  Also you can vote the answer.

Comment: sure I will ask the question again. Ya I vote the answer. @ user3280146

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would do something like

```
t = df[df.columns[0]].astype('int64') / 1e9
print(t)
```

to convert the whole first column. If you only have strings in your table, you need to convert to dates first, something like

```
timecol = df.columns[0]
df[timecol] = pd.to_datetime(df[timecol])
```

and then run the first snippet.

Comment: while I run your code and it gives me an error invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0:06:15' @ Jonas Byström

Comment: It seems you've got strings instead of timestamps in your table. I've added an explanation for how to convert those.